# How do I have an "empty view" in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

So I want to have a view which presents conditionally, depending on the state of my model.  I understand how to do this if each case has a view to present, but how do I handle the case where I want to show *no* view in some cases?

For instance:

```
struct MyView: View {

    enum ViewState {
        case A, B, C
    }

    let state: ViewState

    var view: some View {
        switch state {
            case .A:
                Text("A State")
            case .B:
                Text("B State")
            case .C:
                // empty
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like [EmptyView()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/emptyview)?…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to use `EmptyView` and (!) mark `view` property as a `ViewBuilder`, like in below finalised example:

```
struct MyView: View {

    enum ViewState {
        case A, B, C
    }

    let state: ViewState

    @ViewBuilder var view: some View {    // << here !!
        switch state {
            case .A:
                Text("A State")
            case .B:
                Text("B State")
            case .C:
                EmptyView()         // << here !!
        }
    }

    var body: some View { // replicated for demo
        self.view
     }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EmptyView()` and mark you view with `@ViewBuilder var view: some View`

Comment: After or is make no meaning, ViewBuilder use EmptyView() in case there is nothing to return. In question the Op must return a view for third case, and that should be something. We are not in opaque situation here.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MyView: View {

    enum ViewState {
        case A, B, C
    }

    let state: ViewState

    var text: String {
        switch state {
            case .A:
               "A State"
            case .B:
                "B State"
            case .C:
                ""
        }
    }

    var view: some View {
       Text(text)
    }
}
```